# attach two ASP.NET content page buttons to one masterpage event

Tags: asp.net, events, master-pages, content-pages

I have one master page with two content page each content page has submit button:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" type="image" id="buttonSubmit" name="buttonSubmit"
    alt="ImageButton 1" src="images/button.png" OnClientClick="PreventExitPop=true"/>
```

I want to be able to create one `onclick` event on the `masterpage.cs`:

```
protected void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

and attach the two buttons from the content pages to this event.

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" type="image" id="buttonSubmit" name="buttonSubmit"
    alt="ImageButton 1" src="images/button.png"
    onclick="buttonSubmit_Click"
    OnClientClick="PreventExitPop=true"/>
```

The problem is that each content page knows only his code file and not the `masterpage.cs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write event handlers for each control and in those handlers you call a event handler method in the master page

```
protected void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    ((MasterType) this.Master).buttonSubmit_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: try it like this
((my_master_page_class_name)this.Master).buttonSubmit_2_Click(sender, e);

but VS says cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' to 'my_master_page_class_name'

Answer (score 0):

i think you should not be able to do that, 
and its not true that a event handler bind to two separate event at all...
i think, if you can, you should create your button on master page...
if you can not, you should have two event handler for these buttons, but u can create a method and in this method do everything you want, and call this method from two defined handlers...